# Найти одинаковые числа в векторе

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте , уже задавал этот вопрос и пользовался разными предложенными методами нахождения одинаковых чисел в векторе , но не получается .

```
struct node2
{
    bool operator==(const node2&a) const;
};
for (demanditerator = demandmatrix.begin(); demanditerator != demandmatrix.end(); demanditerator++)
{
    int TotalFrequency = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < points2.size(); i++)
    {

            if (find(points2[i].begin(), points2[i].end(), demanditerator->x&&demanditerator->y) != points2[i].end())
            {
                acceptedRoutesTaker.x = i;
                acceptedRoutes.push_back(acceptedRoutesTaker);
                TotalFrequency += frequency[i];
            }

    }
```

Я уже задавал этот вопрос , но выразил его криво. Надеюсь сейчас тут все понятно . Проблема в том , что у меня выходит ошибка такого вида: 
binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'node2'

А другой вопрос состоит в том , что

```
inVehicleTime += distance[demanditerator->x][demanditerator->y];
```

Но почему-то мои demanditerator выдает ошибку и пишется , Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type?

Я очень жду ваших предложений и заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что код должен делать?

Comment: В цикле for (demanditerator = demandmatrix.begin(); demanditerator != demandmatrix.end(); demanditerator++) находится две цифры ,мне нужно проверить есть ли эти две цифры в другом векторе и если есть , то добавить в третий вектор

Comment: demanditerator->x&&demanditerator->y а вы понимаете что здесь происходит?

Comment: вопрос с Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type, решен

Comment: demanditerator->x&&demanditerator->y  я хочу найти те цифры , которые находятся в первом цикле .. То есть этот итератор отвечает за следующую цифры 69 и 74 , даже если я напишу 69 и 74, то все равно выдает эта ошибка, если я напишу просто 69, тоже самое

Comment: Ваш `find(points2[i].begin(), points2[i].end(), demanditerator->x&&demanditerator->y)` ищет в `points2[i]` элемент со значением `demanditerator->x&&demanditerator->y` - вы именно этого хотите?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так это делается. Код получился обобщенный для любого количества значений.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct ContainValues{
    std::set<int> values;
    ContainValues(const std::set<int> &values):
        values(values)
    {}
    inline bool operator()(const std::vector<int> &v){
        std::vector<int>::const_iterator begin = v.begin();
        std::vector<int>::const_iterator end = v.end();

        while(begin != end && !values.empty()){
            values.erase(*begin);
            ++begin;
        }

        return values.empty();
    }
};

void indexOf(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &vectors, const std::set<int> &values){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>::const_iterator pos = std::find_if(vectors.begin(), vectors.end(), ContainValues(values));

    if(pos == vectors.end()){
        std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Index = " << std::distance(vectors.begin(), pos) << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vectors = {
        {1,2,3,4},
        {5,6,7,8},
        {9,10,11,12},
        {13,14,15,16},
        {17,18,19,20}
    };

    indexOf(vectors, {1, 2});    //Index = 0
    indexOf(vectors, {5, 8});    //Index = 1
    indexOf(vectors, {12, 10});  //Index = 2
    indexOf(vectors, {17, 22});  //Not found
    indexOf(vectors, {21, 42});  //Not found
}
```

Для инициализации контейнеров я использовал фигурные скобки. Если у вас компилятор не поддерживает C++11, то наполняйте контейнеры при помощи методов push_back и insert